Kubernetes HPA scale on average CPU usage for the period of time
Is it possible to configure HPA so that it scales pod only if an average CPU usage is greater than a configured threshold for a specific period of time (e.g. 5 minutes). Couldn't find it anywhere.
Thanks in advance

Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or DevOps. These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

As quoted from Kubernetes documentation:

For per-pod custom metrics, the controller functions similarly to per-pod resource metrics, except that it works with raw values, not utilization values.

This indicates that you can define a custom metric in your application that calculates and exposes the average CPU usage over the desired time window.
The stabilization window is used to restrict the fluctuation of replicas count when the metrics used for scaling keep changing. The autoscaling algorithm uses this window to infer a previous desired state and avoid unwanted changes to the workload scale.
To backup the idea, here's a post from Drew that mentioned that scaling is based on % of requests not limits.
So to configure the HPA to scale pods only if the average CPU usage is greater than a threshold for 5 minutes, the setting for the specification of your HPA would be:
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-deployment
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      targetAverageUtilization: 60
  behavior:
    scaleDown:
      stabilizationWindowSeconds: 300

In this example, the HPA will only scale the pods if the average CPU usage across all pods exceeds 60% for a 5-minute period(300 seconds).
